# sequelize postgres combine fn 'date' with jsonb value

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I need to compare a string of format `MM/DD/YYYY` with another one in postgres on a jsonb column using sequelize.

On a regular column I would do something like

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date', sequelize.col('created_at'), '>=', moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYY'))),
```

but once the value is in JSONB I can't seem to find the way to reference it.

I tried multiple variations:

```
sequelize.col("data ->> 'created_at'")

sequeliez.json("data.created_at")
```

etc...

What is the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 7):

One way I finally found how to do this is using `literal`

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date', sequelize.literal(`data ->> 'created_at'`)), '>=', moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYY')))
```

This works find for me.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)