# How to update column from the nested JSONB value of a separate column?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
UserActivity.update({ 
    type: col("activity.type")
  }, {
    where : { 
      activity: { id: 4285299988 }
    } 
  })
```

Where the column name is "activity" and it's a JSONB field. I need to somehow get the nested "type" property and assign it to a new column called "type".

I can find plenty of examples of how to get nested JSONB values within there where clause, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can use sequelize.literal for this:

```
   UserActivity.update({ 
    type: literal(`activity ->> 'type'`)
  }, {
    where : { 
      activity: { id: 4285299988 }
    } 
  })
```

This answer, although it wasn't specifically related to updates, got me on the right track: [sequelize postgres combine fn 'date' with jsonb value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082164/sequelize-postgres-combine-fn-date-with-jsonb-value/52082313#answer-52082313)